# Extracting coordinates pairs for a string

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, polygon, spatial

I have a bunch of areas defined by the following data

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.38155821054295 29.777919007756058, -82.37586672057267 29.777692426264537,...))
```

I'm wondering if there is any simple way to transform these strings into a format that is usable by either the {sf} package or if there is a recipe that can pivot the pair within the string to respective lat/lon columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the actual data? a `dput()` taking the multipolygon data as argument would be enough..

Comment: Sure, the full dataset is publicly available here: https://data.cityofgainesville.org/Geospatial-Maps-/Color-Coded-Gainesville-Police-Zones/qzci-z4wx

Comment: Here's a single row of `dput()` output: https://pastebin.com/5xJkKwgx

Answer (score 3):

Your data is already in a format (WKT) that can be read by `sf`.

```
df <- read.csv("https://data.cityofgainesville.org/api/views/w6hi-8tsw/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD")

sf::st_as_sfc(df$the_geom)
#> Geometry set for 24 features 
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -82.42229 ymin: 29.5929 xmax: -82.22238 ymax: 29.77834
#> CRS:            NA
#> First 5 geometries:
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.38156 29.77792, -82.37587 2...
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.34404 29.7036, -82.34362 29...
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.40023 29.67428, -82.40003 2...
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.33932 29.64188, -82.33933 2...
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.33221 29.61823, -82.33225 2...
```